# HttpClient 4.X cannot post when I run 2 instances each as a thread, why?

Tags: java, multithreading, httpclient

HttpClient 4.X cannot post when I run 2 instances each as a thread, why?

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
MyThread t1 = new MyThread();
MyThread t2 = new MyThread();
executor.execute(t1);
executor.execute(t2);
executor.shutdown();
while(!executor.isTerminated()) {
}
```

An instance of CloseableHttpClient is created in each instance of MyThread. When I run only 1 thread, it works fine, if I run more than 1 my post does not work returning response code 400.

Any ideas?

Comment: Server does not like the idea?

Comment: what would you recommend?

Comment: Ask the server admin if more than one POST request from the same IP is permitted?